# What is the cartesian equation of an ellipse whose center is $(3,2)$ , whose rightmost vertex is $(5,7)$ and whose semi minor axis $3$ units long?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, rigid-transformation

Desmos construction corrected

Briefly, my questions deals with the shifting terms that have to be applied in order to move the blue ellipse to the purple one :

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gise9qcyfz

The givens of the question are :

(1) the ellipse the equation of which is researched  is centered at $C_f = (3,2)$.

(2) its right vertex is $V_f = (5,7) $

(3) the length of its semi minor  axis is ( arbitrarily) $3$ units

(4) this ellipse is the result of rotating and translating an original  ellipse that is in standard orientation and in standard position ( hence, with its major axis on the X axis , and its center at $(0,0) ) $.

***Step 1 : equation of the original ellipse in standard orientation and in standard position***

Let $S_M$ be the length of the semi major axis; we have : $S_M = \sqrt {(5-3)^2 + (7-2)^2}$   ( because rotation and translation preserve length).

Equation of the original ellipse : $\large  \frac {x^2} { (S_M) ^2} + \frac {y^2} {3^2} =1$

***Step 2 : equation of the rotated ellipse whose major axis will be parallel to the major axis of the final ellipse***

Let $R$ be the angle by which the ellipse is rotated; we have : $R = \arctan \bigg{(} \frac {7-2} {5-3} \bigg {)}$.

Applying the rotation of axis formula , we get :

- $X(x,y) = x \cos(R)+ y \sin(R)$
- $Y(x,y) = y \cos(R) - x \sin(R)$
- and finally, for the rotated ellipse : $\large  \frac { X(x,y)^2  }  { (S_M)^2 } + \frac { Y(x,y)^2 }  {3^2  } =1 $

***Step 3 : shifting the rotated ellipse in order to get the final ellipse.***

What remains to be done is to find the shifting terms $ h$ and $k$ in the final equation :

$$\large  \frac { (X(x,y) -h)^2 }  { (S_M)^2 } + \frac { (Y(x,y) -k)^2 }  {3^2  } =1 $$

If I am correct, these shifting terms " operate" , so to say, in the rotated coordinate system , with

- new X axis :$ y = \tan (R) x $
- new Y axis : $y = (-1/ \tan(R))x $

Let $\gamma$ be the angle point $C_f = (3,2)$ makes with the new ( rotated)  Y axis .

[image]

We have $ \gamma = \arctan (2/3) + ((\pi/2) -R)$.

With $D= \sqrt {2²+3²}$ the distance  from $C_f$ to $O$ , the ( unchanged) origin, the  new coordinates of $C_f$ are $ (h, k) = ( D \sin\gamma , D \cos \gamma)$.

So applying the new coordinates of $C_f$ as shifting terms , it seemed to me that I should have ( for the final ellipse) :

$$\large  \frac { (X(x,y) -h)^2 }  { (S_M)^2 } + \frac { (Y(x,y) -k)^2 }  {3^2  } =1 .  $$

> ***However, the equation that, apparently works requires not a minus $k$ but a plus $k$ :***

> $$\large  \frac { (X(x,y) -h)^2 }  { (S_M)^2 } + \frac { (Y(x,y) +k)^2 } 
>  {3^2  } =1 .  $$

> Since  $h$ and $k$ are both positive numbers , should not the
> displacement to the right  and the displacement in the direction of
> the positive ( new) Y axis require a minus sign in both cases?

Note : I observe the same phenomenon if I directly apply as shifting terms the coordinates of $C_f$ in the original non rotated coordinate system , namely $(3,2)$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get how you computed $\gamma$, but I imagine the root of your problem is the fact that $(h,k) = (D\cos \gamma, D\sin\gamma)$ expand into
$$\cos \gamma = \cos \left ( \frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(2/3) - R  \right )=-\sin\left (\arctan(2/3) - R \right),$$
meanwhile
$$\sin \gamma = \sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(2/3) - R  \right )=\cos \left (\arctan(2/3) - R \right).$$
So that
$$\left ( Y-\left | k \right | \right )^{2}$$
should actually be
$$ \left ( Y-\left(-\left | k \right | \right)  )^{2}=(Y+\left | k \right | \right )^{2}.$$

PS: Please work on your notation. You can stick to complete abstraction replacing all constants with variables, so you won't have *as many* problems with +/-'s. You can also give the variables you provided more meaningful "names". The post was very difficult to comprehend "as is".

Comment: Sincere thanks , Blue, for taking time in order to aswer my  question. I've added an image in order to make easier my definition of angle $\gamma$ ,. The origin of my question lies in a confusion between new  X axis and new Y axis. In the new coordinate system , the center of the ellipse is shifted downwards, contrary to what  I wrongly assumed.